# Random 0x80004003 invalid pointer error on child SSIS packages on new server

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, cluster-computing

We have a new SQL 2008 R2 instance that's part of a cluster (active/passive) on Windows 2008.  I'm testing an SSIS package on the SQL instance that calls many child packages.  It's been dying on random packages (rarely the same one twice) with the following error:

Error 0x80004003 while preparing to load the package.  Invalid pointer.

I can run the individual package from the SSIS package store just fine.  I can also run the master package from BIDS and it'll run perfectly.

I've tried a repair on the SQL instance but there was no difference.  I also tried removing and reimporting all the packages to the SSIS package store, with no change.  My google-fu is weak, because I can't find anything useful in the cloud.

Nothing is in either the SQL server error logs or any Windows error logs.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebuilding the master package from the ground up fixed the issue. Still, if someone has an idea, I'd love to hear it; rebuilding it is a pain on a good day.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue.
I closed the visual studio and restart it as an administrator (Shift + Right Click using the Mouse) and it worked fine with me.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was chaging the protection level on the packages. I set the protection level on the parent and all the child packages to DontSaveSensitive, and re-deployed. No longer received the errors.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem. I used Execute package Utility (EPU) to run Parent package created from BIDS 2008. somehow It gave me error

Error 0x80004003 while loading the package. Invalid pointer.

The issue was having two SQL Server, 2008 R2 and 2012. By default, "EPU" run from SQL Server 2012 which is failed because package created from BIDS 2008. You have to run EPU from SQL Server 2008 folder which execute package successfully.

I hope this help you.

- Yatin Patel